# Sync images between two applications. (manager and user)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, security

I have two separated apps that will be accessed using different IPs.
I want to upload image in first one (like a manager app) and manage it for edits and etc. Users will see the images in the other one.
I don't know really how it's possible, considering the accessibility, security, relative addressing and etc.

(I use .Net MVC for both projects)

*Also I will be grateful if you would help me to select benefit tags for this question.*

Answer (score 0):

all you have todo is to provide full url to the images.

consider that you have Images folder in managers app and it contains all your images, then in users app you have to give full url like below:

```
http://www.managersapp.com/images/image1.jpg
```

Comment: But the users of website shouldn't have permission to access the manager. They are two separated projects.

Comment: by default you can access static files (as images, videos, css, js, ...etc) if you provide full url as above also the files must be under the root folder of the website.